# How to move ChildWindow in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

[This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129329/How-to-Reposition-a-Silverlight-Child-Window) and [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466232/silverlight-childwindow-does-not-reposition-correctly) don't work for some reason. Actually I want my Child Window to recenter itself once it's height changes. For example I add list items and I want it to go a bit upper so that it is still in the center.

Silverlight 4.

Comment: Try http://forums.silverlight.net/p/186375/426799.aspx, it works for me.

Comment: @Ekk the one that was accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am going to answer this question by myselft. [Answer is here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/166750.aspx). Important thing is that where this code is placed. Check full answer by Rui Figueiredo, it is in last post in that topic.